# MSbuild option of skip unchanged files when deploying web application

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

I am looking for solution that When I deploy my .net web application from visual studio . It should only deploy changed files.

I have tried with build TFS 2012 but couldn't find solution. I also reviewed Incremental build but couldn't find exact solution.

Then I searched for MSbuild option to add .wpp.targets file to exclude files and folder , Which is working properly but in this case I have to mention files manually in order to exclude from build.

Then I found MSbuild attribute SkipUnchangedfiles, I have gone through MSDN link but its not working.

How do I achieve this functionality that only changed files will be deployed ??

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to ignore files/folder individually.  By default WebDeploy/MSDeploy does only deployed "changed". WebDeploy checks the timestamp by default to identify changed files.  If you try to deploy the same package twice you will see it will deploy all the files and then no files on the second run.  The problem is each build updates the files’ Dateime stamp and creates a new package.  So even the unchanged files will be flagged as new because of the new timestamp.

There is a second option where WebDeploy will use a checksum value instead of datetime.  You can add the `-useChecksum` WebDeploy flag to use the second method.

OR from MSBuild you can add the `/p:MSDeployUseChecksum=true` argument which will set the MSDeploy flag.

OR from your wpp.targets file you can add the following property:

```
<MSDeployUseChecksum>true</MSDeployUseChecksum>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I have tried this option in both scenarios. 1. in TFS build parameter it didn't worked but in wpp.target file it worked . Now timestamp is changing of only modified files. But problem is whole build is egtting deployed . I mean all files and folder and folder time is always new though files inside it is having different time now

Comment: Adding this option will not change whether the files have modified times.  It only effects what files are deployed to the target.